# Process form login/register with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the next javascript and html to login and register users in my web page.

I have the login and register code into same html.

When I click on login, the register form disappears, until here all good.

Now, When I click on register, the login form should be disappears. This is my problem, it doesn´t disappears.

if needed I can post the full source code of the page as showing in chrome.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
     // Add smooth scrolling to all links in navbar + footer link
    $('#login-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#login-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#register-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#register-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#register-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#register-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#login-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#login-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
   })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="panel panel-login">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <a href="#" class="active" id="login-form-link">Login</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <a href="#" id="register-form-link">Register</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12" id="col_login">
                                <form id="login-form" action="#" method="post" role="form" style="display: block;">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group text-center">
                                        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" class="" name="remember" id="remember">
                                        <label for="remember"> Remember Me</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                                <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Log In">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                <div class="text-center">
                                                    <a href="http://phpoll.com/recover" tabindex="5" class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <form id="register-form" action="#" method="post" role="form" style="display: none;">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" value="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="confirm-password" id="confirm-password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                                <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-register" value="Register Now">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like it works to me.  Click the Run Code Snippet button.

Comment: It works mate! I guess you should copy paste this whole code

Comment: Seems to work properly. Try it in other browser.

Comment: Sorry, I am using delphi with intraweb and bootstrap. I am trrying to do this form works with them. Is it a problem of my web app server or of the browser?

Comment: Works perfect, Chrome, latest beta release.

Comment: @Robert Harvey To work with Intraweb I had to add a new form(dummy form) before <form id="login-form" action="#" method="post" role="form" style="display: block;">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">. I don´t have  how to explain it.